# How to create a read-only model attribute in pynamodb?

Tags: pynamodb

I'm working on a model which implements a read-only attribute with a simple hack:

```py
from pynamodb.models import Model


class MyModel(Model):
    […]
    updated_at = UTCDateTimeAttribute()

    def save(self):
        self.updated_at = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        return super().save()
```

With this hack the user needs to provide `updated_at` when creating an instance, even though the value will be ignored.

That immediate issue could be solved by `updated_at = UTCDateTimeAttribute(null=True)`, but now the model signals that `updated_at` might not be part of the response, which is not the case.

Basically, how can I signal to the user that they *cannot* provide a value for a field (ideally trying to set `updated_at` should result in an error), but that every instance of this model will have a value for this field?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `__init__` method of `MyModel` to check for the presence of `updated_at` in passed attributes, and raise an Exception if it is present:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, hash_key=None, range_key=None, _user_instantiated=True, **attributes):
        if "updated_at" in attributes.keys():
            raise IllegalArgumentException
        super().__init__(
            hash_key=hash_key,
            range_key=range_key,
            _user_instantiated=_user_instantiated,
            **attributes,
        )
```

Similar updates to the `save` and `update` methods that check that the object that is being saved has an identical `updated_at` value to the object in the DB should be sufficient for the requirements above.

Comment: That's a neat idea; does it actually work with a mandatory (`null=False`) attribute?

Comment: It should work with non-nullable fields as long as `updated_at` is set prior to calling `super.save()`. So with the example above where `updated_at` is set in the save method I believe this would work. It would also be possible to explicitly set `attributes["updated_at"] = datetime.now(timezone.utc)` after the check in the constructor.